# I'm stuck on this Calc 3 question, any help is very appreciated?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, physics, parametric, parametrization

> A person throws an object with mass $m$ nearly vertically with an initial momentum $\vec{p} = (p_x, p_y, p_z)$. With respect to the cartesian coordinate system where the person is looking in the direction $y$, with $x$ directed to their right. Let $q$ be the elevation angle of the initial momentum (with respect to the $xy$-plane) and let $\theta$ be the angle of the initial momentum with respect to the $yz$-plane. Write parametric equations for the trajectory of the center of mass of the object.

I am completely stuck. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be that q and theta are the same? Or is the person possibly not throwing in the direction they are looking?

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS**

1. Since you know the initial momentum $\vec{p}$ and the mass $m$, can you find the initial velocity $\vec{v}_0$?
2. Knowing $\vec{v}_0$, can you write down the equations for the trajectory of the object in each dimension independently?
3. Can you now parameterize them together in one framework?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do these.